# String assigned to PATH variable

Tags: linux

I am a new to Linux/Unix programming and was learning form the tutorial: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-environment.htm

In the tutorial it says that the .profile file in the home directory
initializes the TERM variable and initializes the PATH variable 
to: $PATH=/bin:/usr/bin$

However, when I print the contents of my .profile file, I get the following content:

```
 1  # ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
 2  # This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
 3  # exists.
 4  # see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
 5  # the files are located in the bash-doc package.

 6  # the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
 7  # for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
 8  #umask 022

 9  # if running bash
10  if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
11      # include .bashrc if it exists
12      if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
13      . "$HOME/.bashrc"
14      fi
15  fi

16  # set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
17  PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

My question is that the

(1) TERM variable is nowhere initialized?

(2) PATH variable is initialized to garbage(?) - because I can't find any folder called 'HOME', so the paths 
$HOME/bin and $HOME/.local/bin don't make sense; also which folder is $PATH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Where is TERM set?

For `1` see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198794/where-does-the-term-environment-variable-default-get-set. On your command line, you can type:

```
echo $TERM
```

If you get no output, that means TERM variable was not set. Just FYI, if TERM is the variable, you can output its value by using $TERM.

## What is HOME/$HOME?

For `2`, HOME is set to your home directory. If you logged in as kaind, chances are that your HOME variable is set to /home/kaind. Its value can be retrieved using $HOME. See https://superuser.com/questions/271925/where-is-the-home-environment-variable-set to see how HOME is set.

## What is PATH/$PATH?

`PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"` means that PATH variable is set to a `:` delimited paths. First one is $HOME/bin. That expands out to /home/kaind/bin. Then, you have $HOME/.local/bin. That expands out to /home/kaind/.local/bin. And so on.

## How your program can get executed?

If you had an executable file in $HOME/bin or $HOME/.local/bin, you can type that program right at your command line without needing to provide a full path.

For example, let's say you have a folder called /home/kaind/scripts. In that, you have an executable file called run.sh. You have work.sh under /home/kaind/bin.

In order to execute run.sh, you would have to type:

```
$> /home/kaind/scripts/run.sh
or
$> $HOME/scripts/run.sh
or
$> ~/scripts/run.sh (~ is an alias for $HOME)
```

In order to execute work.sh from under /home/kaind/bin, you can type the full path but you don't have to since /home/kaind/bin (aka $HOME/bin) is in your PATH. So, you can type:

```
$> work.sh
```

to execute it. When a program is typed, paths listed in PATH variable are checked one by one. If the program is found, it gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

The $TERM variable is an environment variable, which controls whether your terminal will have a color or not. The variable $HOME is set to your home directory. To see where this is you can do:

```
echo $HOME
```

or

```
cd $HOME
```

You need to prepend $ to the beginning of the variable, otherwise bash won't know that you are referring to the variable and treat it like a string instead.